# A story about zero gravity wings

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember a name/author of the story that had a person designing "wings" for humans to fly in zero gravity on a space station. In the end, they also ended up with swimming in water in addition to flying in air.

The story was before 1990; not too long. I read it translated into Russian (to narrow the possibilities) but originally was in English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The story is "[For the Birds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_the_Birds_%28short_story%29)" by Isaac Asimov.

It's a science fiction story about a clothing designer brought to a space habitat to design wings. The idea is that the people can exercise in low gravity by flying. The designer comes up with the correct answer: low gravity is not flying; it is swimming.

You can read the full text [here](http://www.archive.org/stream/yamisaacasimovss1980asimrich/yamisaacasimovss1980asimrich_djvu.txt);